# Does `Amplify.configure()` require network connection?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I'm using [AWS-Amplify](https://docs.amplify.aws/start/q/integration/android) to download some files from S3. The library is configured by calling `Amplify.configue()` once in `Application.onCreate()`, as suggested by the [docs](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/project-setup/create-application/q/platform/android#n4-initialize-amplify-in-the-application).

From time to time, `configure()` fails with the following exception:

> AmplifyException {message=Failed to instantiate AWSMobileClient within 10 seconds, cause=null, recoverySuggestion=Check network connectivity}

So, does `configure()` require network connection? If so, and it can fail, why is it recommended to call it just once on app creation?

Comment: I am trying to learn more in this issue: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-android/issues/1727 if others have any more input